# Strip leading 'u' from JSON for PHP

Tags: php, python, json, character-encoding

I have the following which I'm trying to parse in PHP

It's JSON but with leading 'u' (probably python indicators, but I'm not sure)
What's the quickest way to turn these into valid JSON?   Or is this
already valid JSON that PHP should be able to parse?

```
{u'_id': u'fruit',
               u'etags': [{u'score': 3.612, u'tag': u'apple'},
                          {u'score': 1.443, u'tag': u'banana'},
                          {u'score': -0.833, u'tag': u'cherry'},
                          {u'score': -2.048, u'tag': u'orange'}]}
```

*Edit:  I do get a "Syntax error, malformed JSON" in PHP so something is off,
but it may not be the 'u'*

*Edit: Not a great answer,  but this is getting the trick done for me:*

```
$json = str_replace("u'", "'", $json);
$json = str_replace("'", '"', $json);
```

Comment: The 'u' means a unicode literal.

Comment: @iCodez In python? In php? Where?

Comment: Whoops, sorry.  In Python.  Although, I'm pretty sure it is that in PHP as well.

Comment: This isn't JSON, these are Python lists and dicts.  Encode it to JSON in Python before passing it to the PHP code.

Comment: Also, your sample starts with a `{` but ends with a `)`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a great answer, but this is getting the trick done for me:

```
$json = str_replace("u'", "'", $json);
$json = str_replace("'", '"', $json);
```

Answer (score 5):

You're doing something wrong here. Assuming you have something like this in python

```
data = {u'_id': u'fruit',
           u'etags': [{u'score': 3.612, u'tag': u'apple'},
                      {u'score': 1.443, u'tag': u'banana'},
                      {u'score': -0.833, u'tag': u'cherry'},
                      {u'score': -2.048, u'tag': u'orange'}])
```

You're currently doing the equivalent of

```
print repr(data)
```

You should be doing:

```
import json
print json.dumps(data)
```

The string you're parsing is not JSON because it:

- has a `u` where it shouldn't
- uses `'` instead of `"`
- does not encode `None` as `null`
- ...

---

Since you do not control the data source, you have no choice but to invoke the python interpreter on the input:

```
import ast
import json

bad_json = get_from_server()
data = ast.literal_eval(bad_json)
print json.dumps(data)
```

Comment: Fixing the source of the invalid JSON data is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks,  I do not control the data source

Comment: @OneSolitaryNoob: Then you have to use a python literal parser, because what you have there is a python literal, not a json string,

Comment: @OneSolitaryNoob The `...` at the end of this answer is because there's certainly even more problems with attempting to convert this at the destination - like entities that might be in the strings.  This is not reliably fixable at the destination without using `json.dumps()` in Python code.